# How to retrieve a users contacts and present them in a UITableView?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, addressbook

Forgive my ignorance, but I'v mainly done game programming and not much Utiliy like apps. What I'm trying to do is Retrieve a Users contacts and present them in a table view on app launch. I'm not a complete noob I know my way around the Address Book API. I'm just unsure how to complete the task of getting the users contacts into my own custom UITableView. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how good my response is going to be, because I haven't use the Address Book API, but a little bit of searching + my own knowledge suggest the following:

### Create the Address Book

One way to do this (based on my searches) seems to be the following:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate( );
CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople( addressBook );
CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount( addressBook );

for ( int i = 0; i < nPeople; i++ )
{
    ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex( allPeople, i );
    ...
}
```

### Display the Address Book

Using the code from above, you now need to display it inside your table. I don't know how familiar you are with using `UITableView`, so I am going to be more verbose than what I probably need. You are going to have populate the following methods of your tableView class:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSections
{
    //You can also return 26 here, but you'll need to split your addressBook array, so each section contains the people starting with a single letter of the alphabet
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [addressBook count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //do standard cell instantiation
    //get the contact at index indexPath.row
    //set the cell's textLabel.text to that contact's name (or whatever you want)
}
```

I don't know how helpful my response was, but if you want me to clarify something (or tell me that I am being silly assuming your problem is so simple), feel free to let me know.